# Check array if value exist in array. If yes delete it.

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays and I would like to find and delete the same values.

For example:

```
$array_1=array('a','b','c');    
$array_2=array('3','43','b');
```

Final result should like:

```
$final_array=('a','b','c','3','43');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$final_array = array_unique( array_merge($array_1, $array_2) );
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
$final_array = array_unique(array_merge($array_1, $array_2));
```

Manual from [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/array_merge) says

`If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.`

In your case duplicate values are appended after `array_merge`, so you need to call [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/function.array-unique) after merging to remove duplicate values.

Comment: I was almost about to post this :-) you guys are rock!